# Facing a CORS ERROR in local server

Tags: php, http-headers, cors

I'm sending a post request with `XMLHttpRequest` to my other domain in local but I get the CORS error below:

> Failed to load http://another.local/: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://example.local', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://example.local' is therefore not allowed access.

I had set header in PHP as below:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *",false); //header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header("Content-type:application/json");
readfile('data.json');
```

Despite setting the header, I'm still getting the CORS error; what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: what's the new cors error after you snippet code?

Comment: Try `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Comment: You might find it easier to use the `fetch` api - it has proper support for CORS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API. It might help if the ajax code was added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I fix this problem.
I use Laragon for PHP development and I don't know its Laragon configuration or apache that by default they set this in the config file:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

and this makes conflicts with headers that I set in PHP. I comment it and can set headers with no problems.

thanks to @Thamaraiselvam & @rahul-mukherjee for helping me.

Comment: saved my day :)

Comment: I added this line into my ````httpd.conf```` (at the bottom). But it's not working. I restartedeverything.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

And also check whether you have the same header twice

Comment: no difference.
Failed to load "http://another.local/": The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin "'http://example.local'" is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Check you have added same header twice `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin)`

Comment: Why should TO allow **every** origin out there instead of only his own domain? O.o

Comment: thanks for your helping but my another PHP script contains only 4 line code. so twice scenario is impossible.

Comment: can you post that 4 lines?

Comment: @Andreas yes you are correct, but seems he has the confusion the 2 domains. so opened up for all, for debugging.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam Yep, I edit question and past my all PHP code

Comment: The code seems fine. can you remove all other headers and only do allow-origin

Answer (score 0):

You can try with 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.local', false);

if you have not set the http methods you can use :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ACCEPT, CONTENT-TYPE, X-CSRF-TOKEN");
```

**Note:** please change the values as per your requirement:

Comment: Thank you but with/without false still get the same error.

Comment: Are you using all the headers or just access-control? Could you please use all the headers required and have look .. thanks !